# Rabbitmq change local host to ip address C++

Tags: c++, rabbitmq

Quick question. Why can't I replace localhost with an IP address?
When I do it just freezes. I've went through the java tutorials and I am able to do it but for some reason it dosen't work in C++.

I am Using this link
https://github.com/RPG-18/rabbitmq-cpp-tutorials

```
#include

#include "SimplePocoHandler.h"

int main(void)
{
    SimplePocoHandler handler("localhost", 5672);

    AMQP::Connection connection(&handler, AMQP::Login("guest", "guest"), "/");
    AMQP::Channel channel(&connection);

    channel.onReady([&]()
    {
        if(handler.connected())
        {
            channel.publish("", "hello", "Hello World!");
            std::cout << " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'" << std::endl;
            handler.quit();
        }
    });

    handler.loop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate the java tutorials you have tried, and confirm you have tried there to change the IP interface with the same `guest` user?

Comment: Here are the java tutorials https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html

Comment: Even if I change the credentials to test, test (credentials I've made in the rmq management plugin) it still doesn't work with the C++ code above

Comment: https://github.com/RPG-18/rabbitmq-cpp-tutorials/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

After looking around [the sources](https://github.com/RPG-18/rabbitmq-cpp-tutorial) for a couple minutes, I have found the following:

Check out the connection constructor for the AMQP-CPP tests [here](https://github.com/RPG-18/rabbitmq-cpp-tutorials/blob/d6a1ad0213ad5ea7c0ae627a88f30ef4cbe134e6/3rdparty/AMQP-CPP-2.1.4/tests/myconnection.cpp#L29-L39). Notice that an ip address is passed in as a string but is converted to a specific class using `Network::Ipv4Address(ip)`.

Now, look at the `SimplePocoHandler` constructor [here](https://github.com/RPG-18/rabbitmq-cpp-tutorials/blob/d6a1ad0213ad5ea7c0ae627a88f30ef4cbe134e6/src/SimplePocoHandler.cpp#L87-L93) it takes a host name as a string and passes that string to `Poco::Net::SocketAddress address(host, port)` which is then used as the argument to `connect`.

So, in your case, when you pass `192.168.1.100` as an ip address, it's really using that as a host name. You will have to modify the `SimpePocoHandler` constructor to use `Network::Ipv4Address(ip)`, or create a separate, ip address aware constructor.

Comment: Any advice on how to get started on "You will have to modify the SimpePocoHandler constructor to use Network::Ipv4Address(ip)"?

Comment: That is a basic C++ programming question. If you provide a git repository (via GitHub, for instance) with your current code I could fork it and provide guidance.

Comment: I am using this reposiroty.

Comment: I am trying to adjust the Send file